# How many bodies does Yuma Kuga have?

Tags: world-trigger

Every trigger user have two bodies: his original flesh body, and the Trion combat body. When he activates his trigger, the flesh body is stored inside the trigger, and is physically replaced by the Trion body.

But Yuma's trigger permanently stored his flesh body (black haired) inside, and he lives with a Trion body (white hair).

In ep. 1 or 2 when he crashes into a car, his face shows a crack (causing Mikumo to become certain Kuga is a neighbor) - the same kind crack Aftokrator's magnetic shard trigger user (forgot his name - the one defeated by Jin in ep.29) shows.

Also when he activates a trigger, he undergoes the same transformation as any trigger user, and have a combat body. Proof is that he seems a bit surprised in Ep.8 when he deactivates his trigger (after the Miwa Squad ambush at the abandoned train station) and his severed arm returns.

So, besides the two bodies (flesh body and Trion combat body), does Yuma Kuga have a third intermediary body from his black trigger?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, he indeed has three bodies, but nonetheless he only has access to two of them at any time.

1. Yuma's fleshly body is safely stored in suspended animation inside the black trigger ring his father created. Inside the ring, time passes ever so slowly that Yuma's certainly fatal wounds have not yet killed him even three years after the incident. This body is black-haired.
2. The "civilian" trion body. The one he uses whenever a trigger is not active. This body is made of Trion (see the scene in ep.2 when he is run over by a car, leaving only a small crack on his face). This body supposedly requires nutrients (since Yuma is shown to be eating). It has white hair.
3. The trion combat body, that replaces the civilian body (or is morphed into) when Yuma goes "trigger on". During the fight with Miwa squad in the abandoned train station, this body has an arm cut off. When Yuma "trigger off", the combat body is dissolved and the intact civilian body is replaced.
    3.1 Also during his fight with Viza in ep. 34, Viza successfully kills Yuma combat trion body, and his black trigger restores the civilian body. Being made of Trion, Yuma uses the inertia of his movement and a seal to burst through Viza's combat body. Viza is seen remarkably surprised for all his combat experience.

It is supposed<sup>(whom?)</sup> that if and when Yuma is able to heal his flesh body, the black ring will stop mantaining the trion civilian body.

Answer (score 0):

Yuma does not have a third body, he only has 2, the real body stored in the trigger and the trion body he lives with.

In ep 8, he was not surprised, he was just checking whether his arm was working fine after he regenerated it using his own trion as trion bodies can be repaired with trion if the trion was not supplied to a trigger.

In the episode when he used Osamu's trigger, a new border tigger based trion body was created based on his trion body from his black trigger as he was using that trion body when the trigger was activated.

Therefore, if he were to use another such as Osamu's trigger while in his white-haired trion body, a third trion body would be created using his white hair trion body as a base.

Prove is that in ep 23, he had to deactivate his border trigger to utilise his black trigger as the trion body he was using was not the one from his black trigger.

Comment: Ep 23 transition was very fast, and since they cut that transformation sequence for some time (the one with the sparkling "curtain" that changes the bodies), it is unsure if he really switched back and forth. But your answer has a contradiction, he indeed can have a second combat body if he uses a normal trigger, you said. Hence three bodies.

Comment: I meant to say there was a special case for him to use another trigger and get another body, but normally he would only have 2.